# How to merge elements in a matrix

Tags: matlab, matrix

```
x = [1 2 3 4 5
     1 2 3 0 0];
```

I want to get off all zeros and merge the two rows

```
newx = x(:,1) + x(:,2)(nonzeros)
     = [1 2 3 4 5 1 2 3];
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`nonzeros`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/nonzeros.html) will give you nonzeros in a column vector, you just have to orient the original matrix properly and transpose into a row vector (if that's what you want):

```
>> newx = nonzeros(x.').'
newx =

   1   2   3   4   5   1   2   3
```

Comment:  +‍l ‍‍‍‍‍‍ ‍‍ that's far better  

Answer (score 1):

```
newx=x.';        %Taking Transpose
% Converting the given matrix into a column vector and then taking transpose again
% (since you require answer as a row vector)
newx=newx(:).' ; 
newx(newx==0)=[]  %Removing zeros
```

or  using [**`reshape`**](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/reshape.html):

```
newx = reshape(x.',1,[])
newx(newx==0)=[]  %Removing zeros
```

**Result:**

```
newx =

     1     2     3     4     5     1     2     3
```